# I changed my CPU but my computer won't post into BIOS

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i5, intel-pentium

I upgraded my cpu from an intel pendium G440 into intel i5 94000F to y computer having a motherboard ASUS H110D D3. The result was that my computer won't post into BIOS.

I checked and connection and cleaned any piece of dust. Though it won't post either, even the fans won't budge 4 while. Also the ASUS H11D D5 afaik it is an LGA-1151 socket as my CPU is.

So do you have any idea why?

Comment: ASUS H11D D5 I mention it above.

Comment: It's very rarely worth upgrading the CPU on the same motherboard, if it works the gains are negligible, and if the CPU is much better then the motherboard most likely won't support it.

Comment: [This](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/58667/intel-celeron-processor-g440-1m-cache-1-60-ghz.html) claims the G440 is an LGA1155, not 1151.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just replace a low-end CPU from 2015 with a newer medium class CPU from 2019 and expect it to work. Even if both CPUs use the FCLGA1151 socket the BIOS needs to support the newer CPU.

Hence the first step would be before using the new CPU to upgrade the BIOS to the latest version. <s>Also you should check if the new CPU respectively CPUs from the "Coffee Lake Refresh"/"9th Generation" are supported by the BIOS at all.</s>

Edit: **According to some sites I found the chipset H110 of your Mainboard does not support Coffe Lake CPUs. Officially the H110 chipset only supports CPUs up to the 7th generation ("Kaby-Lake").** 
Some hobbyist have managed to run a Coffe Lake CPU with this chipset by BIOS manipulations but that is out of scope for regular users.

Additionally I looks like the new CPU does not have a graphics card integrated. Hence your computer will not be able to display anything unless you have an PCIExpress graphic card installed.

Last but not least, the new CPU has maximum power consumption of 130 Watt where your old had a maximum of 54 Watt. Hence most likely you need a new CPU cooler and may be even a new PSU.

Conclusion: Your CPU is too new for the Mainboard. You need to buy an older CPU or a get new Mainboard to make it run.

Comment: My computer has an PCI-Express graphics card so graphics won't be an issue. And the PSU is a 5000W one so power not an issue at all.

Comment: 5000 Watts? Unlikely.

Comment: 500W it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure that ASUS H11D D5 is your motherboard model?
I tried to find It in google, but I couldn't.

You may reinstall your old CPU and run windows, then provide as the correct motherboard model.
You can also check the model on the motherboard itself, **It's easier**.

Comment: Sry it is an `ASUS H110D D3`

Comment: Look at this page: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H110M-D-D3/HelpDesk_CPU/ and You'll notice that your new CPU isn't supported by your motherboard. You may buy a used 6th gen CPU. Otherwise, You'll need to buy a new motherboard.